# getkey / getchar without terminal window

Tags: python, linux

I would like to have a getkey / getchar function that reads a key from the keyboard. Cavet, the programm does not run in a terminal window, but is executed by a shortcut from linux.

Answer (score 1):

You could throw up a window using Tkinter, and react to KeyPress events:

```
import Tkinter as tk
class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        self.master = master
        master.geometry('200x200+0+0')
        master.bind('<KeyPress>', self.react_to_keypress)
    def react_to_keypress(self, event):
        print(event.char)  # change this; since there will be no terminal
        self.master.quit()

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thats a good solution, but it needs to close the window and exit the programm

Comment: Call `self.master.quit()` in `react_to_keypress`.